# book info needed about game theory

Tags: reference-request

can you suggest me a good book on game theory undergrad/grad course,that may provide insight instead of preaching about computation?it would be better if the works of Neumann & Nash are explicitly discussed..

Comment: the two requests in the question go into opposite directions: most historical discussions of the work of von Neumann and Nash are doomed to give little insight into game theory.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be the books of Dixit and Nalebuff:

[http://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Strategically-Competitive-Business-Paperback/dp/0393310353/ref=la_B000AQ1F26_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1397676399&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393310353)

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Strategy-Theorists-Business/dp/0393337170#reader_0393337170](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393337170)